# OVH VPS Cannot Connect To HTTPD

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, centos-7, vps

Ok, So I recently bought a VPS from OVH. I can connect to SSH and SFTP. I have setup HTTPD to host a server from `/var/www/instinct-main/` on the port `80`, here is where the problem comes in, on the VPS I can run the command `curl localhost` and it will show me the html of my main page. However when I try to access the website through ANY means outside of my vps it doesn't let me connect. It just spits errors along the lines of "Connection Timed Out", It isn't my firewall because I don't even have the firewall enabled yet. And just to be safe I even used the `firewall-cmd` command to open the port `80/udp` and it still doesn't let me connect.

How should I go about debugging/fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Well I figured it out.

I thought that I needed port 80 open on UDP but it turns out that it was supposed to be opened on TCP.

I ran this command:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp`

and then `firewall-cmd --reload`

and a few seconds after I did that my browser refreshed automatically and the webpage was open.